# Is an ungrounded outlet for a gas stove a safety hazard?

Tags: grounding

House was built in the 50's and there is a 3 prong outlet but no ground wire. I've tested it best of my knowledge, the metal casing is not ground either.  2 black and white wires. Basically, am I going to kill myself cooking dinner one day?

Model# NX58H5600SS

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the receptacle box please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/bB5vCP8

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet, from a safety perspective, is to provide GFCI protection to the circuit.   You then label the 3-prong outlet "GFCI Protected - No Equipment Ground".  That will bring it up to code and render it safe.

The GFCI device can be at the breaker or anywhere appropriate to protect as much of the circuit as you want to protect.

Comment: Is a GFCI breaker less likely to trip than a GFCI outlet with the stove and fridge?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the fridge on that outlet I would pull a grounding wire in since you are concerned. As long as the ground comes from the same service panel your outlet is connected to this is legal and you would have a proper 3 wire outlet without the problematic tripping of a GFCI.

The ground can come from another circuit if you possibly have one in the area or back to the service panel.
Code recently changed and now allows a separate wire to be brought in as long as it is from the same service panel that the circuit originated in.

Answer (score 1):

Well, somebody cooked Dinner for 70 years. The chance that you die from an not present ground wire is pretty slim. But of course it would be saver in case of a short to ground and an installed gfi outlet.

Nothing I would have sleepless nights over but if you upgrade the kitchen it  would be in my list.

Comment: The old stove used only gas via pilot light. I have installed a GFCI outlet but the fridge must plug into the same outlet without an extension cord, which I'm unsure about. Having both plugged in trips the outlet randomly.